How detect frequency and duration of beeps in wav files?
I have a  some test.wav file, and I need to get the frequencies of sounds and their length from this file. To test my solution, I created a test.wav sound with these "beeps":
1500 Hz for 100 ms, 1900 Hz for 300 ms, 1200 Hz for 10 ms and 1900 Hz for 300 ms
And I expected my solution to print "beeps" indicating frequency and length. But my solution ignored short beeps for 10ms (and after some experiment I found out that my solutions ignore all beeps that are shorter by 100ms (and it also increases some frequencies)
My non-working solution:
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

def extract_frequencies_and_durations(wav_path, frame_duration=0.02, freq_tolerance=5):
    rate, audio_data = wavfile.read(wav_path)
    if audio_data.ndim > 1:
        audio_data = np.mean(audio_data, axis=1)
    frame_length = int(rate * frame_duration)
    frequencies = []
    durations = []
    current_freq = None
    current_duration = 0
    for i in range(0, len(audio_data), frame_length):
        frame = audio_data[i:i + frame_length]
        fft_spectrum = np.fft.fft(frame)
        freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft_spectrum), 1 / rate)
        magnitude = np.abs(fft_spectrum)
        dominant_freq = abs(freqs[np.argmax(magnitude)])
        if current_freq is None or abs(dominant_freq - current_freq) > freq_tolerance:
            if current_freq is not None:
                frequencies.append(current_freq)
                durations.append(current_duration)
            current_freq = dominant_freq
            current_duration = frame_duration
        else:
            current_duration += frame_duration
    if current_freq is not None:
        frequencies.append(current_freq)
        durations.append(current_duration)
    
    return frequencies, durations

# output
wav_path = 'test.wav'
frequencies, durations = extract_frequencies_and_durations(wav_path)
for freq, dur in zip(frequencies, durations):
    print(f"{freq:.2f}Hz - {dur * 1000:.2f}ms")


How can I fix this solution or what other solution is there?

The frame duration is guessed at 0.02s which impacts the frequency analysis since the frame could be cut in the middle of the wave and not at the end of a full cycle.
The best guess seems to be the duration of the shortest burst that gives the better freq/duration results.
print("Test audio: 1517:0.05; 1921:0.3; 1245:0.01; 1977:0.3\n")
wav_path = 'test2.wav'
frame_duration = 0.01
print(f"frame_duration={frame_duration}")
frequencies, durations = extract_frequencies_and_durations(wav_path, frame_duration=frame_duration)
for freq, dur in zip(frequencies, durations):
    print(f"{freq:.2f}Hz - {dur * 1000:.2f}ms")

frame_duration = 0.02
print(f"\nframe_duration={frame_duration}")
frequencies, durations = extract_frequencies_and_durations(wav_path, frame_duration=frame_duration)
for freq, dur in zip(frequencies, durations):
    print(f"{freq:.2f}Hz - {dur * 1000:.2f}ms")

Generated audio:
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=f=1517:d=0.05[0];sine=f=1921:d=0.3[1];sine=f=1245:d=0.01[2];sine=f=1977:d=0.3[3]; [0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1" test2.wav

Result:
Test audio: 1517:0.05; 1921:0.3; 1245:0.01; 1977:0.3

frame_duration=0.01
rate: 44100, frame_duration: 0.01, frame_length: 441
1500.00Hz - 50.00ms
1900.00Hz - 300.00ms
1200.00Hz - 10.00ms
2000.00Hz - 300.00ms

frame_duration=0.02
rate: 44100, frame_duration: 0.02, frame_length: 882
1500.00Hz - 40.00ms
1900.00Hz - 300.00ms
1250.00Hz - 20.00ms
2000.00Hz - 300.00ms

As a special case, let's generate a base frequency and its harmonics.
Then set the frame_duration to the period of the base
print("f1=441; f2=882; f3=1760; f4=3520\n")
wav_path = 'test2.wav'

frame_duration = round(1/441, 4)
print(f"\n\nframe_duration={frame_duration}")
frequencies, durations = extract_frequencies_and_durations(wav_path, frame_duration=frame_duration)
for freq, dur in zip(frequencies, durations):
    print(f"{freq:.2f}Hz - {dur * 1000:.2f}ms")

The result looks good except at the end that breaks due to the length of the remaining samples that equals exactly the period of the base.
f1=441; f2=882; f3=1760; f4=3520

frame_duration=0.0023
rate: 44100, frame_duration: 0.0023, frame_length: 101
436.63Hz - 50.60ms
873.27Hz - 301.30ms
1746.53Hz - 9.20ms
3493.07Hz - 301.30ms
2450.00Hz - 2.30ms

As a last test let's make the burst duration 10, 20, 100 and 200 periods of the base fequency.
frame_duration=0.0023
rate: 44100, frame_duration: 0.0023, frame_length: 101
436.63Hz - 23.00ms
873.27Hz - 46.00ms
1746.53Hz - 232.30ms
3493.07Hz - 460.00ms
3226.83Hz - 2.30ms

Frequencies improve a lot if frame_duration is set to the period of the base without rounding.
frame_duration=0.0022675736961451248
rate: 44100, frame_duration: 0.0022675736961451248, frame_length: 100
441.00Hz - 22.68ms
882.00Hz - 45.35ms
1764.00Hz - 231.29ms
3528.00Hz - 458.05ms
3675.00Hz - 2.27ms

